# Node.js server side application starter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am starting a new Android app, and I would like to know what should be the best server-side stack that I could use. 
I heard some about MeanIO, MeanJS, Cleverstack, Generator Angular Fullstack. 
Which of these suggestions should be the best? Is there another one that is not on the list that would be even more interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct in saying it depends in what you're doing and trying to focus on.  If you wish to also build a web-based front-end it's probably necessary to include AngularJS.  If you aren't planning on doing that you could probably cut out the need for Angular.

I imagine the MEAN stack (https://github.com/meanjs/mean) would be enough for your Node.JS server.  I doubt you will need to use Angular for an android app so you will be more focused upon the Express+Node+Mongodb portions.